# Coger rango de posiciones de un array

Tags: php, array, php7, lógica

Este es el contenido de array:

```
$aux_explode = [
  0 => "INFRACCION LEY DE SEGURIDAD VIAL ART. 40-2 TIPO INF.: GRAVE"
  1 => "ESTACIONAR SOBRE UN PASEO O ZONA PEATONAL IMPIDIENDO EL PASO DE LOS PEATONES"
  2 => "AV MARQUÉS DE SOTELO CRUCE CON C/ CONVENT DE SANTA CLARA"
  3 => "VEHICULO MATRICULA: 3554KWR - MARCA:SILENCE S02"
  4 => "AGENTE: 21492 REF: MU 2021 89 47106940 - 6 FECHA: 30/08/2021 H.:16:20"
]
```

Entonces me gustaría guardar en una variable el contenido de la posicion 1 hasta la 3 sin hacer esto:

$hechoDenunciado = str_replace(PHP_EOL, " ", $aux_explode[1] . " " . $aux_explode[2]). " " . $aux_explode[3]);

Es decir, no se si puede coger un rango como [1-3] osea desde 1 al 3 o si tuviese mas posiciones el array de 1 al 10 por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso podrías usar [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-slice.php)  combinado con [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php).

Por ejemplo, si quieres obtener los valores de los tres primeros elementos:

```
$aux_explode = [
  0 => "INFRACCION LEY DE SEGURIDAD VIAL ART. 40-2 TIPO INF.: GRAVE",
  1 => "ESTACIONAR SOBRE UN PASEO O ZONA PEATONAL IMPIDIENDO EL PASO DE LOS PEATONES",
  2 => "AV MARQUÉS DE SOTELO CRUCE CON C/ CONVENT DE SANTA CLARA",
  3 => "VEHICULO MATRICULA: 3554KWR - MARCA:SILENCE S02",
  4 => "AGENTE: 21492 REF: MU 2021 89 47106940 - 6 FECHA: 30/08/2021 H.:16:20",
]  
    ;

$hechoDenunciado = implode(PHP_EOL,(array_slice($aux_explode, 0,3)));
echo $hechoDenunciado;
```

**Salida:**

```
INFRACCION LEY DE SEGURIDAD VIAL ART. 40-2 TIPO INF.: GRAVE
ESTACIONAR SOBRE UN PASEO O ZONA PEATONAL IMPIDIENDO EL PASO DE LOS PEATONES
AV MARQUÉS DE SOTELO CRUCE CON C/ CONVENT DE SANTA CLARA
```

Si revisas la documentación verás que `array_slice` te permite establecer a partir de qué índice quieres empezar a obtener los elementos (2º parámetro) y cuántos elementos quieres (3er parámetro). Así, si quisieras `3` elementos a partir del índice `2`:

```
$hechoDenunciado = implode(PHP_EOL,(array_slice($aux_explode, 2,3)));
echo $hechoDenunciado;
```

**Salida:**

```
AV MARQUÉS DE SOTELO CRUCE CON C/ CONVENT DE SANTA CLARA
VEHICULO MATRICULA: 3554KWR - MARCA:SILENCE S02
AGENTE: 21492 REF: MU 2021 89 47106940 - 6 FECHA: 30/08/2021 H.:16:20
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido.

Comment: @Azor considera marcar la respuesta si esto ha servido para resolver tu problema, de modo que pueda servir para futuros usuarios con un problema similar. Saludos.